# How do I give multiple arguments(width, sigh, grouping) in Python format string mini-language?

Tags: python, string, format, f-string, mini-language

I read [format string mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) from Python doc and tried to do this:

```py
a = 20000 # I want "+20,000.00     " for the result 

print(f"a:+,.2f") # >> +20,000.00
print(f"{a:<20+,.2f}") # >> ValueError: Invalid format specifier

print(f"{a:<20,.2f}") # >> '20,000.00           '
print(f"{a:+<20,.2f}") # >> '20,000.00+++++++++++' # Not what I want
```

Anything else will give `ValueError: Invalid format specifier` to me.

Why is it not possible to use `<20` argument with `+` argument?

Actually I found this nested form works but it is suboptimal. Is there any other way?

```py
print(f"{f'{a:+,.2f}':<20}") # >> '+20,000.00          ' # It works but nested form sucks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Asksed the same question on [r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython) and got [the answer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/n6yw1h/how_do_i_give_multiple_argumentswidth_sigh/gx9xq45/?context=3)

---

efmccurdy

15 minutes ago

The sign goes before the width:

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/format.html

```
>>> f"{a:<+20,.2f}"
'+20,000.00          '
>>>
```